# How to find all matches to a regular expression in a string

Tags: text-processing, awk, regular-expression, gawk

In POSIX awk and Gawk respectively, how can we find all the matches to a regular expression in a string?

More specifically,  find all the matches that are substituted by `gsub` builtin function, in terms of either of the following two objectives:

- find the position and length of each match in the target string, and
- find the matches as substrings of the target string only.

Achieving the first objective implies achieving the second objective.

1. In  POSIX awk,

   Is there a builtin function which can achieve either of the two
   objectives?

   Does the `match` builtin function only find the leftmost and longest
   match?

   To achieve the first objective, is it a correct way to repeatedly
   apply `match` to the suffix of the target string created by finding
   each   match and removing the match and the prefix before it from
   the target string?  Is
   https://gist.github.com/mllamazing/a40946fcf8211a503bed a correct
   implementation?
2. In Gawk,

   does `array`  after a call `patsplit(string, array, fieldpat, seps)`
   store the matches as required in the second objective? Can the
   locations of the match location  be found from `array` and `seps`,
   based on that `seps[i]` is the separator string between `array[i]`
   and `array[i+1]`?

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be `awk`? You could use PHP `preg_match_all()` or Python `re.findall()`.

Answer (score 4):

> 1. In POSIX awk,
>      Is there a builtin function which can achieve either of the two objectives?

No.  You can achieve the same effect, but not with a single builtin function.

> Does the `match` builtin function only find the leftmost and longest match?

Yes.  Regular expressions in POSIX `awk` (and GNU `awk`) are always greedy (i.e. longest match always wins).

> To achieve the first objective, is it a correct way to repeatedly
>       apply `match` to the suffix of the target string created by finding
>       each   match and removing the match and the prefix before it from
>       the target string?

Yes, but if you want 100% compatibility with `gsub()` the details are pretty tricky.

> Is https://gist.github.com/mllamazing/a40946fcf8211a503bed a correct
>       implementation?

Mostly, if you remove the [gsub line](https://gist.github.com/mllamazing/a40946fcf8211a503bed#file-findallmatches-awk-L12).  The devil is in the details: the code will loop if `regex` is an empty string.  Classic `awk` didn't allow empty regexps, but IIRC `nawk` did.  To fix that you could do something like this:

```awk
function FindAllMatches(str, regex, match_arr) {

    ftotal = 0;
    ini = RSTART;
    leng = RLENGTH;

    delete match_arr;

    while (str != "" && match(str, regex) > 0) {
        match_arr[++ftotal] = substr(str, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        str = substr(str, RSTART + (RLENGTH ? RLENGTH : 1))
    }

    RSTART = ini;
    RLENGTH = leng;
}
```

That's not 100% compatible to `gsub()` however, because

```
$ echo 123 | awk '{ gsub("", "-") } 1'
-1-2-3-
```

while the function above finds only 3 matches (namely, it misses the match at the end).

You could try this instead:

```awk
function FindAllMatches(str, regex, match_arr) {

    ftotal = 0;
    ini = RSTART;
    leng = RLENGTH;

    delete match_arr;

    while (match(str, regex) > 0) {
        match_arr[++ftotal] = substr(str, RSTART, RLENGTH)
        if (str == "") break
        str = substr(str, RSTART + (RLENGTH ? RLENGTH : 1))
    }

    RSTART = ini;
    RLENGTH = leng;
}
```

This fixes the problem above, but it breaks other cases: if `str = "123"` and `regex = "[1-9]*"` the function finds two occurrences, `123` and the empty string at the end, while `gsub()` finds only one, `123`.

There may be other similar differences, that I can't be bothered to hunt right now.

> 2. In Gawk,
>
>    does `array`  after a call `patsplit(string, array, fieldpat, seps)`
>      store the matches as required in the second objective?

Mostly yes.  However, corner cases related to regexps can be unexpectedly subtle.  There may be *some* differences, as above.

> Can the
>       locations of the match location  be found from `array` and `seps`,
>       based on that `seps[i]` is the separator string between `array[i]`
>       and `array[i+1]`?

Yes.